# Further Integrating Google Cloud Build with GitHub Checks API

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I have installed Google Cloud Build in a GitHub project of mine and added a Dockerfile and cloudbuild.yaml that I am, so far, happy with. The build passes or fails based on unit tests and lint rules.

However, when I look at the checks tab in GitHub, all I see is this:

[image: limited summary]

Which is very uninformative. I would prefer not to have to go into Google Cloud Build to figure out why the build failed.

I would like to be able to break down Build into Test and Lint subgroups and each of those would have their actual results (or some subset of them).

How can I do that?

Comment: This is something that Google would need to support. You should contact them.

Comment: @osowskit Unfortunately, I am not in the higher tier of support, so their recommendation is to ask questions here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the integration with Google Cloud is *very* recent for GitHub: [end of July 2018](https://blog.github.com/2018-07-26-simplify-your-ci-process/): that can still evolve as a service.

What you see, for now, is described as:

> Cloud Build uses the new [Checks API](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/), a better way to get feedback from integration on your code. Once a build is complete, you can see rich status reports, annotated code, and detailed information—all without leaving GitHub.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/896475/43161255-9893c828-8f55-11e8-94ed-d35f986db1cc.png]

For now, [Google adds](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/07/go-fast-safely-and-easily-with-cloud-build-and-github.html):

> ### Insights:
>
> Once the build is complete, details about build times, failures and artifacts are available within GitHub through the Checks API, so you can understand and diagnose build results from within the familiar GitHub environment.
> **Full logs and history are available in Cloud Build’s UI in the Google Cloud Console.**

Comment: I suppose the reason it isn't documented is because it isn't available, yet. I hope they add support for tweaking the results seen in GitHub soon. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any progress on this? I'd like to see details of my "check steps": test, lint, prettier... I didn't find any info. Thanks.

Comment: @nerotulip In the context of the recent (August 2019) CICD integration offering (https://twitter.com/github/status/1159511691480260608), You might have to check GitHub Actions, like https://github.com/actions/gcloud.

Comment: @VonC Thanks, I didn’t see this announcement. However, I already have access to Github Actions (2018 beta), but I can’t access the new one (August 2019), even in a new repo: I still have the old interface... do you have any clue?

Comment: @nerotulip that seems to be limited indeed: https://twitter.com/github/status/1159510891718742018. Being in the 2018 beta does not give you access to CICD?

Comment: @VonC Apparently feature flag will be flipped in the next weeks for 2018 beta users https://twitter.com/arikfr/status/1159535657708113921?s=20

Comment: @nerotulip OK, makes sense.